# How to make a program instruction callable by a qrcode?

Tags: wallet, program, solana-pay, web3.js

Just like @solana/pay did it. It’s possible to invoke an arbitrary transaction (for example a program instruction) using a QR code and scanning it for example from phantom mobile app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [solana pay transaction requests](https://docs.solanapay.com/core/transaction-request/overview) for this.

With transaction requests, it’s now possible to bring **any** Solana transaction into the real world through an interactive request.

You can return an arbitrary (doesn't have to be payments related) transaction as part of a [transaction request](https://docs.solanapay.com/core/transaction-request/overview)

The flow is documented here:

[image: diagram of a transaction request]

Comment: UPDATE: I finally implement this and is open source! You can find this at our [repo](https://github.com/staratlas-italia/frontend)